# How do I identify the blank fields in the csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I have a csv file with 5 columns:

```
1, 2312, "A", , 20
2, 8383, "B", "UK", 
3, 3883, , , 45
```

where the columns represent id, customerId, customerName, customerAddress and customerAge.
I want to put `0` at the place where the age is blank and `''` where the other string type attributes are blank. But I can't identify the blank field in python. I have tried doing some things like:

1. `len(row[4]) == 0`
2. `row[4] == ''`
3. `row[4] == None`
4. `repr(row[4]) == ''`

but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If possible, you should put your code up here

Answer (score 3):

you want to use `not`

`0`, `None`, `False` , `''` are all `not True`

```
if not row[4]:
```

you could also do

```
bool(row[4])
```

which will return `False` for all the above mentioned values