# How do I get Python to recognize blank/empty cells in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with data output from a web service my company uses to get transaction from certain clients. The data output is a mess and I'm working on a Python script to make it more usable. Many cells in the CSV are blank, and I want to incorporate that into an IF statement. Basically, I want to do something like the following:

```
IF (CSV CELL) == (BLANK):
    DO X
ELSE:
    DO Y
```

I know that the blank cells correspond to a certain type of transaction, so I always want to do a particular thing when there's a blank cell in the CSV file.

Comment: print out `CSV_CELL` and see what its value is in case of an empty cell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319950/how-do-i-identify-the-blank-fields-in-the-csv-file-in-python?rq=1 might help

Comment: Thanks to both of you - this is what I needed!